# bash permissions - unknown problem

Tags: permissions, ls, amazon-ec2

So strangely enough I have the following problem in a directory inside a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MAIN_DIR=/home/ec2-user/dir/
LAST_DIR=$(ls -d -t ${MAIN_DIR}*/ | head -1)
```

When I run it I get:

```
ls: cannot access /home/ec2-user/bitcoin/*/: No such file or directory
```

If I run it in terminal everything is fine.

Additionally I thought it might be a premission issue so I did `chmod 777 -r` to the directory and still nothing. Any ideas how to fix it?

**Note**

This is on Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: does it exist ? /home/ec2-user/bitcoin/

Comment: Please show us the actual output from your actual test script. You seem to have censored it inconsistently: `dir` vs `bitcoin`. What does the directory `/home/ec2-user/bitcoin` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `/home/ec2-user/bitcoin/*/` expands to the list of subdirectories of the directory `/home/ec2-user/bitcoin`, because of the trailing slash. (Except that directories whose name starts with a `.` are omitted.) If `/home/ec2-user/bitcoin` doesn't contain any subdirectory, then the pattern doesn't match anything, so it's left unmodified.

---

Aside: don't run `chmod 777` just because you don't understand what's happening. There are extremely few problems that this solves and many that it can cause. It's like saying “I can't see through where I think my window is so I'll drill a hole in the wall.”

Comment: Excellent.  It's also possible that the drill is not a drill, it's a gun, and that's not the wall, it's your foot.

Comment: So it turned out I was deleting one of the folders at some earlier point in the script, so in fact there was no other folders left... which is why I got the error. As the chmod 777, I know, but sometimes if you are in a hurry just helps me to know if its a permission issue, since on these servers I'm still a bit confused when I call a script under which permissions group it is executed as sometimes with for instance 740 it was complaining it could not write to some of the files, yet I'm suppose to be the 7...

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is the way you've defined your variables. Rather than writing this:

```
MAIN_DIR=/home/ec2-user/dir/
LAST_DIR=$(ls -d -t ${MAIN_DIR}*/ | head -1)
```

I'd recommend you omit the trailing `/` from `MAIN_DIR` and use it where required, like this:

```
MAIN_DIR=/home/ec2-user/dir
LAST_DIR=$(ls -d -t ${MAIN_DIR}/*/ | head -1)
```

This, I suspect, may help you identify what is going on. Without seeing what's inside `dir` and `bitcoin` I can't suggest anything more specific.

As a style issue, I'd also strongly recommend that you quote variables (and their values) so that unexpected spaces in values don't break your code:

```
MAIN_DIR='/home/ec2-user/dir'
LAST_DIR=$(ls -d -t "${MAIN_DIR}"/*/ | head -1)
```